# How to reinstall Ubuntu on a dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, reinstall

My laptop has two hard disks 256GB (SSD) & 1TB (HDD).

I have Windows 10 installed on the SSD and Ubuntu (18.04.4LTS Desktop) on a 300GB partition on the HDD.

I had a lot of driver issues with Nvidia drivers and most notably Audio drivers (Dummy Output) and now WiFi drivers which it doesn't even recognize my Wireless adapter now.

I have Ubuntu partitioned on the 300GB partition of the 1TB(HDD) as followed> (50GB for / partition), (12GB for /swap partition), (512MB for /boot partition) & (the rest of the 300GB for /home partition).

My question is how should I reinstall Ubuntu on these partitions (Which partitions should I format which I should leave them as is) & whether should I install a different version other than (18.04.4LTS) or not because I'm having a lot of trouble with drivers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Always use the "LTS" version for good measure when drivers are an issue and for partitioning it's up to you but I would suggest giving the "/" partition a bit more space since we have our "var" folder in there!

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, So should I delete all partitions and start over? and give / like 70GB or what do you suggest?

Comment: And I heard that /swap is not needed anymore,
 so should I delete it as well and reassign it for another partition?

Comment: Is this an UEFI install or BIOS install? Be sure to install in same boot mode as Windows UEFI or BIOS. I do like to have an ESP - efi system partition on every drive, but Ubuntu's Ubiquity will only install grub to ESP on first drive. I use ESP on sdb as backup or reconfigure after install to use it. You can use 30 to 50GB for /. How full is current /? If /home separate partition you  should not need a large /. You should not need /boot nor swap unless you hibernate which is not recommended anyway with dual boot. It will create a swap file for system use. you can reuse existing /home.

Comment: My / partition had only 10gb used of its total capacity.
So what do you recommend? Have / set for 50GB, and delete both /swap & /boot and reassign the rest for /home?